# Namespace class conflict

Tags: c#, namespaces

First of all, I know that this is because of bad libraries, but I don't have code for them to fix this.

XXX.dll contains class Util in global namespace.
Util.dll has namespace Util.

When I include both .dlls I can't use Util namespace (Error 1   The namespace 'Util' in '..\Util.dll' conflicts with the type 'Util' in '\XXX.dll').

Because both are in global namespace I don't see how aliasing can fix this.

What is best solution for this? For now i know that I can make another .proj which will not include both .dlls and wrap classes I need. But this is not easily done ;(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use [extern aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) for this - they allow you to effectively qualify a reference with which assembly you mean. Anson Horton has a good [walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) for them.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a solution to your problem. Go to the `References` subfolder in your project referencing the two assemblies. For the assembly with the global `Util` right click and press `Properties`. In the `Aliases` property you should have `global`. Change that for example to `DLL1` or whatever. Now if you like to use the global `Util` in a file add the following before your `using` statements:

`extern alias DLL;`

Now you can use the global `Util` like that `DLL.Util`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the "extern alias" language feature. Check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) blog entry by Anson Horton.

(Or just see Jon's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

This error may also show up when [upgrading a DevExpress project](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18674)

1. Close `Visual Studio`
2. Clear `Temporary ASP.NET Files` directories by clearing the following folders:

   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`
   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`
   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`
   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`
   - `C:\Users\[your_user_name]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`
   - Restart the `World Wide Web Publishing` service (Start menu\Settings\Control Panel\Administrative tools\Services).
3. Clear the project's **Bin** and **Obj** folders and deploy new assemblies if it is necessary;
4. Rebuild your application

Comment: This is not a build bug, it is a name conflict which can't be resolved with rebuild.

Comment: @watbywbarif - I understand your point but sometimes this error is thrown because of un-deleted old versions of `.dll`s. I've simply covered that scenario. I've tested these steps for today itself for the same error

Comment: This is an issue, and I do this to clear an issue like this.

Comment: @Greg I suggest you to add this as a suggestion to the answer I have written by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37674750/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this ... class files in folders will inherit their namespace from the folders name. Make sure that any folders you add don't have a corresponding file name in the root of the same project.